# How do I properly include systematic uncertainty of x and y values correctly into fitting parameters (y=ax+b)?

Tags: least-squares, uncertainty, error-propagation

I am doing a simple experiment that involves measuring the resistance of a wire. To do this, we measure the voltage across a wire as we increase the the current going through it with two Fluke Digital Multi-Meters.

The Fluke user manual lists the uncertainty as +- 0.3% + 1. So for a voltage reading of 3.000 V the uncertainty would be (3.000 V * 0.003) + 0.001 = +-0.010. For the current which is measure in mA, it is +- 1.5% + 3.

We have ten data points and we fit a y = ax + b line to find the resistance (the slope).

We took five measurements at each current value, but the statistical random error was much less than the devices reported error.

**My question** : If the error associated with the device is not a random error, does the uncertainty in the slope parameter (using Least-Squares) actually represent the true uncertainty in the value? Do I need to propagate it differently since (from my understanding) least-squares fitting account for statistical random error?

Below is the graph:

[image]